# laravel update Has Many Relation for items in invoice

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to update items in the invoice, and I need and the problem when deleting item or add an item if I delete all item it updates I need help, please 
i get error message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'product' in 'field list' (SQL: update `invoice_product` set `id` = 27, `invoice_id` = 29, `product_id` = 3, `unit_price` = 80, `qty` = 1, `created_at` = 2018-10-08 16:54:53, `updated_at` = 2018-10-08 16:54:53, `deleted_at` = , `product` = 3 where `invoice_id` = 29 and `id` = 27)"

**invoice table**

- id
- invoice _no
- date
- sub_total
- discount
- total

**items table**

- id
- item_code
- item_desc
- unit_price

**invoice_items table**

- invoice_id
- item_id
- unit_price
- qty

**invoice model**

```
public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(InvoiceProduct::class, 'invoice_id');
    }
```

**my controller update**

```
$invoice = Invoice::findOrFail($id);

        $items = [];
        $itemIds = [];
        $subTotal = 0;

        foreach($request->items as $item) {
            if(isset($item['id'])) {
                InvoiceProduct::where('invoice_id', $invoice->id)
                    ->Where('id', $item['id'])
                    ->update($item);

                $itemIds[] = $item['id'];
               $item ='please re add items';
            } else {
                $items[] = new InvoiceProduct($item);
            }

            $subTotal += $item['unit_price'] * $item['qty'];
        }


        $data = $request->except('items');
        $data['sub_total'] = $subTotal;
        $data['total'] = $data['sub_total'] - $request->discount;

        $invoice->update($data);

        InvoiceProduct::whereNotIn('id', $itemIds)
            ->where('invoice_id', $invoice->id)
            ->delete();

        if(count($items)) {
            $invoice->items()->saveMany($items);
        }
 return response()
            ->json(['saved' => true, 'id' => $invoice->id]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a `Many to Many` relationship. your relationship should be `belongsToMany()`.

**Model Relationships**

```
class Invoice extends Model
{
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class)
            ->withPivot(['unit_price', 'qty']);
    }
}

class Item extends Model
{
    public function invoices()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Invoice::class)
            ->withPivot(['unit_price', 'qty']);;
    }
}
```

**Manipulating Data**

```
public class InvoiceControler extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $reques)
    {
        // save the invoice
        $invoice = Invoice::create([
        ...
        ]);

        // save invoice-items
        foreach($request->items as $item) {

            $invoice->intems()->attach($item['id'], [
                'unit_price' => $item['unit_price'],
                'qty => $item['quantity']
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Invoice $invoice)
    {
         // update the invoice with new request data.
         $invoice->update([
         ...
         ]);

         // items to be synchronize
         // $items = [];

         // create an item array to synchronize
         foreach($request->items as $item) {

            array_set($items, $item['id'], [
                'unit_price' = $item['unit_price],
                'qty' = $item['qty']
            ]);

         }

         // synchronize items.
         $invoice->items()->sync($items);
    }
}
```